# Installing Kwikset Kevo on a door to control more than the deadbolt

Tags: doors, lock, deadbolt

I own door which the key not only controls the lock but also to open the door. There is no extra handle to open the actual door. You just turn they key once more and the door opens. 
I wish to install a Kwikset Kevo on that door and would like to know before I buy if this is feasible and how to do it

**EDIT**
[[image: Inside the house[1]]
In the image above you see the inside of the door. Key position to lock the door and a handle on the side to opwn the door when unlocked.

[image: outside thw house]

In the above image you see how the outside of the door is. The key on the outside controls both the lock and door opening, while on the inside only locking.

Comment: got a picture of the door with a detail shot of the current lock?

Comment: I will take one this afternoon and post it yes

Comment: @ratchetfreak added images